# Java String encoding

Tags: java, string, encoding

What´s the difference between

```
"hello world".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

and

```
 Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").array();
```

?
The second code produces a byte array with 0-bytes at the end in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second snippet uses [`ByteBuffer.array()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array--), which just returns the array backing the `ByteBuffer`. That may well be longer than the content *written* to the `ByteBuffer`.

Basically, I would use the first approach if you want a `byte[]` from a `String` :) You *could* use other ways of dealing with the `ByteBuffer` to convert it to a `byte[]`, but given that `String.getBytes(Charset)` is available and convenient, I'd just use that...

Sample code to retrieve the bytes from a `ByteBuffer`:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world");
byte[] array = new byte[buffer.limit()];
buffer.get(array);
System.out.println(array.length); // 11
System.out.println(array[0]);     // 104 (encoded 'h')
```

Comment: Just observed that `byte[] b1 =  "hello world".getBytes("UTF-8");byte[] b2 = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").array();`. `b1.length` prints out 11 and `b2.length` prints out 12.

Comment: @Sandeep: Yes, because the `ByteBuffer` has presumably been allocated with a backing array of length 12. If you call `limit()` on the `ByteBuffer` instead, you'll just get 11 bytes...